# Sustituir imagen al pasar el mouse y hacer transición (CSS)

Tags: css

Tengo la siguiente imagen por html:

```
<img id="imagen1" class="imagen" src="img/imagen-1.png" alt="">
```

Lo que deseo hacer es que al pasar el mouse sobre esa imagen se sutituya por la imagen-2.png pero con una transicion de 0.3s para que el cambio no sea tan brusco, y al salir de la imagen esta regrese a la imagen-1.png de igual manera con transición.

¿Es posible hacerlo solo con CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código hace lo que necesitas:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Cambiar imagen con hover</title>
 </head>
<body>
 <div class="imagen">
    <!--imagen1-->
    <img src="https://biblioteca.acropolis.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/rojo.png" />
    <!--imagen2-->
    <img class="arriba" src="https://biblioteca.acropolis.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/verde.png" />
 </div>

<style>
 body{
  background: white;
 }

 .imagen {
  position: relative;
  height: 290px;
  width: 290px;
  margin: 50px 20px;
  float: left;
 }
  /*aquí te agregue el efecto de transición en 0.3segundos*/
 .imagen img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
 }
 /*y con hover detectamos si el puntero de mouse esta por encima*/
 .imagen img.arriba:hover {
  opacity: 0;
 }
</style>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias @Dani Daniel, justo lo que necesitaba.